# Camel case and Pascal case mistake

Tags: naming-conventions

I constantly forget which is Camel case and which is Pascal case. So I thought that maybe a little history will help. Where do the names of these conventions come from? Is there some history behind their names?

Comment: Just remember the phrase - A *sleeping camel* will always have his head *lower*. Hence the first case is lower case in camel case. This is the only difference between the two naming conventions.

Comment: Something I heard that I like is: Pascal is a proper noun, so the first letter is a capital. However, camel is not, it's just a noun, so the first letter does not need to be a capital.

Comment: If you're interested in naming conventions and history, check out 'Hungarian Notation' just for fun.

Comment: I always thought Pascal case was named after the programming language [Turbo Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Pascal), my first true love! Nobody mentioned that? Pascal was case-insensitive, but PascalCase was the convention.

Comment: Remember that CamelCase sucks as a term because it is ambiguous as the first letter can be upper or lower.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

To remember camel case you have to think about the shape of the capital letters. They are like the humps of a camel as you can see in [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/CamelCase_new.svg/2560px-CamelCase_new.svg.png) image.

**Pascal Casing** - capitalizes each word:

`ThisShouldBePascalCase`

**Camel Casing** - is similiar to pascal case but the first word is not capitalized:

`thisShouldBeCamelCase`

You can read some history [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2004/02/03/history-around-pascal-casing-and-camel-casing/)

UPDATE:
Change the camel case image after reading the comments.

Comment: I don't think the "CamelCase" picture is helpful because it uses Pascal Casing—the first letter is capitalized.

Comment: This one is better: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case#/media/File:CamelCase.png

Comment: While I'd known of this method, I could never remember if the camel's head counted as a capital letter.  ‍♀️

Comment: @Ema.jar please note that Camel Case may have first letter lower or upper. Please correct your statement "but the first word is not caplitalized[sic]".  Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case

Answer (score 53):

Pascal is a persons name... a persons name always starts capitalized, whereas 'camel' is just a noun and thus, unless the start of a sentence, is always lowercased.

Comment: @Nick This answer is different from the accepted answer, because it provides a completely different _mnemonic device_ to remember the difference between PascalCase and camelCase.

Comment: @CameronBieganek, SO is for technical information, not mnemonics.

Comment: @Nick OP was looking for help remembering which was which, and this answer provides that help in the form of a mnemonic. Judging by the number of upvotes for this answer, I'm guessing other people were also looking for a way to remember which is which.

Comment: Also SO is a resource for learning, and it's sometimes helpful to have many point of views and/or additional information. I believe that's one purpose of being able to add *many* answers to a single question.

Answer (score 11):

**camel case** - first letter of first word lower case, and first letter of every word, after that should be Upper Case.

Examples:

- **c**amel**C**ase
- **c**amel**C**ase**L**etter

---

**pascal case** - first letter of every word should be upper case.

Examples:

- **P**ascal**C**ase
- **P**ascal**C**ase**L**etter

Answer (score 1):

Pascal Case:
in Pascal case every word of each letter should be capital like MossawarHussain

Camel case:
As the name show it follow the camel structure of word like mossawarHussain

Difference:

Pascal is a subset of Camel case. The first letter of Pascal is capital and first letter of the camel is small that is the major difference between these two cases.

Comment: So if Pascal case is a subset of Camel case, then Pascal case is also Camel case, right? For ex, `VariableName` is written in Pascal case, but it's also written in Camel case. Am I right?

Comment: I believe what the author meant was that, with a `camelCase` symbol, if you remove the initial lower case letters, you end up with a `PascalCase` word (just like if you take the camel case "*someVeryLongSymbol*" and remove the "*some*" in the front, you get the pascal case "*VeryLongSymbol*"). In reality, `camelCase` is **not** `PascalCase`, and `PascalCase` is **not** `camelCase`.

Comment: For set **PascalCase** to be a *subset* (or proper subset ⊆) of set **camelCase**, (PascalCase ⊂ camelCase) it means that EVERY member of PascalCase is also a member of camelCase - but that intersection is the empty set (∅).  It's also false that camelCase is a subset (⊂) of PascalCase because the intersection of those sets is also the empty set (∅).

Answer (score 0):

In camel case first letter of first word lower case, and first letter of every word, after that should be Upper Case.

Ex:
userName
userFullName

In pascal case first letter of every word should be upper case.

Ex:
UserName
UserFullName

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong.  PEP 8, for those writing in python, suggests otherwise.
i.e.  in python => CamelCase
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: That python PEP reference which shows PascalCase and calls it "camelCase", and shows camelCase and calls it "mixedCase" is an example of don't believe everything you read on the internet - not all sources are authoritative, even the ones that purport to be.

Comment: @Steven the Easily Amused,   "I don't believe it"  ;-)