# java generic function parameter type mismatch for "Object" class

Tags: java, function, generics, parameters, extends

I've got following code snippet:

```
class pp<K, V> {
    public pp(K k, V v) {
        this.k = k;
        this.v = v;
    }

    private K k;
    private V v;
}
class my{
    public static void f(pp<? extends Object, ? extends Object> p){
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
public class genericFunction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        my.f("abc", new Integer(2));//compilation failure
    }
}
```

It fails to compile inside the main. Saying looking for

```
pp<? extends java.lang.Object,? extends java.lang.Object>
```

but found

```
java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a `pp`, you have two arguments.

Put them in your object type: `my.f(new pp<>("abc", new Integer(2)))`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are passing literal arguments (String and Integer) instead of passing an object of `pp`.

Try `my.f(new pp<>("abc", new Integer(2)))`

Side note: use [Pascal casing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768733/camel-case-and-pascal-case-mistake) for type names