# Is there a built in way of using snake case as the naming policy for JSON in ASP.NET Core 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

I managed to get it working using the following code:

```
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
    };
});
```

However this makes MVC use `Newtonsoft` rather than `System.Text.JSON` which is faster, async and built in.

Looking at the naming policy options in `System.Text.JSON` I could only find CamelCase. Is there any native support for snake case? What is a better way of achieving snake case JSON naming style?

Comment: I thought that asp.net core does this out of the box. No additional config needed. Am I wrong?

Comment: It doesn't do snake case, it does camel case by default

Answer (score 46):

**Update**

.Net 8 has been released and it has built in support for different naming [policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-8-0#customize-individual-property-names).

```
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    // This can be changed to other naming policies like SnakeCaseLower, KebabCaseLower
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    WriteIndented = true
};
jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast, serializeOptions);
```

**Old Answer**

Just slight modification in **pfx** code to remove the dependency on `Newtonsoft Json.Net`.

`String` extension method to convert the given string to `SnakeCase`.

```
public static class StringUtils
{
    public static string ToSnakeCase(this string str)
    {
        return string.Concat(str.Select((x, i) => i > 0 && char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + x.ToString() : x.ToString())).ToLower();
    }
}
```

Then in our `SnakeCaseNamingPolicy` we can do

```
public class SnakeCaseNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
{
    public static SnakeCaseNamingPolicy Instance { get; } = new SnakeCaseNamingPolicy();

    public override string ConvertName(string name)
    {
        // Conversion to other naming convention goes here. Like SnakeCase, KebabCase etc.
        return name.ToSnakeCase();
    }
}
```

The last step is to register our naming policy in `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()            
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => { 
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = 
                    SnakeCaseNamingPolicy.Instance;
            });
}
```

Using the model:

```
public class WeatherForecast
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureCelcius { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureFahrenheit { get; set; }

    public string Summary { get; set; }
}
```

`Json` output:

```
{
  "date": "2019-10-28T08:26:14.878444+05:00",
  "temperature_celcius": 4,
  "temperature_fahrenheit": 0,
  "summary": "Scorching"
}
```

Comment: Actually it's not wrong. C# property naming convention is [PascalCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768733/camel-case-and-pascal-case-mistake). So, CPU is considered three different words. There two solutions you can use is either use `[JsonPropertyName("CPU_power")]` or change the property name to `CpuPower`.

Comment: What is the reason for using the PropertyNamingPolicy = SnakeCaseNamingPolicy.Instance instead of PropertyNamingPolicy = new SnakeCaseNamingPolicy() ? I tried the 'new' variant and as far as I can see, this works perfect.

Comment: @NielsLucas Since no state needs to be stored in order to convert to snake case, there is no need to create a new instance of the naming policy every single time.  This creates unnecessary allocations which will lead to decreases in performance.

Answer (score 19):

At the moment there's no builtin support for snake case,
but `.NET Core 3.0` allows to set up a **custom naming policy** by inheriting from [`JsonNamingPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonnamingpolicy?view=netcore-3.0).

You need to implement the `ConvertName` method with the snake case conversion.
*(Newtonsoft Json.NET has an internal [`StringUtils`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/StringUtils.cs#L206) class which shows how to handle this.)*

---

The POC implementation below, re-uses Json.NET's `SnakeCaseNamingStrategy` only for the snake case conversion *(, whereas the whole application uses `System.Text.Json`)*.

**It is better to avoid having a dependency on Newtonsoft Json.Net for only the snake case conversion, but in this rather LAZY example below I don't want to rethink/reinvent a snake case conversion method.

The main point of this answer is how to hook a custom policy (and not the snake case conversion itself.)**  *(There are many libraries and [code samples](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/StringUtils.cs#L206) that show how to do so.)*

```
public class SnakeCaseNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
{
    private readonly SnakeCaseNamingStrategy _newtonsoftSnakeCaseNamingStrategy
        = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy();

    public static SnakeCaseNamingPolicy Instance { get; } = new SnakeCaseNamingPolicy();

    public override string ConvertName(string name)
    { 
        /* A conversion to snake case implementation goes here. */

        return _newtonsoftSnakeCaseNamingStrategy.GetPropertyName(name, false);
    }
}
```

In `Startup.cs` you apply this custom `SnakeCaseNamingPolicy`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()            
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => { 
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = 
                    SnakeCaseNamingPolicy.Instance;
            });
}
```

---

An instance of the class below

```
public class WeatherForecast
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureCelcius { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureFahrenheit { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("Description")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }
}
```

will have a `Json` representation as:

```
{ "date" : "2019-10-28T01:00:56.6498885+01:00",
  "temperature_celcius" : 48,
  "temperature_fahrenheit" : 118,
  "Description" : "Cool"
}
```

Note that the property `Summary` has been given the name `Description`,
which matches its `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyNameAttribute`.

Comment: FYI there's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/782) opened to track the implementation of a `JsonSnakeCaseNamingPolicy` directly in `System.Text.Json`. As of July 23, 2021, the implementation is scheduled for .NET7.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/J0rgeSerran0/JsonNamingPolicy) with `SnakeCase` and `KebabCase` support for `System.Text.Json`, also a nuget package is available.

**nuget**

> PM> Install-Package JorgeSerrano.Json.JsonSnakeCaseNamingPolicy

**SnakeCase NamingPolicy**

```
var person = new Person { FirstName = "Jorge", Birthday = DateTime.UtcNow, MyJobCity = "Madrid" };

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = new JsonSnakeCaseNamingPolicy() };
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(person, options);
```

**KebabCase NamingPolicy**

```
var person = new Person { FirstName = "Jorge", Birthday = DateTime.UtcNow, MyJobCity = "Madrid" };

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = new JsonKebabCaseNamingPolicy() };
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(person, options);
```

Answer (score 3):

I share a full implementation of @pfx 's solution here. The custom naming policy (copied from NewtonSoft):

```
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Utils
{
    public class SnakeCaseNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
    {
        public override string ConvertName(string name) => JsonUtils.ToSnakeCase(name);
    }

    public class JsonUtils
    {

        private enum SeparatedCaseState
        {
            Start,
            Lower,
            Upper,
            NewWord
        }

        public static string ToSnakeCase(string s) => ToSeparatedCase(s, '_');
    
        private static string ToSeparatedCase(string s, char separator)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            {
                return s;
            }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            SeparatedCaseState state = SeparatedCaseState.Start;

            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                if (s[i] == ' ')
                {
                    if (state != SeparatedCaseState.Start)
                    {
                        state = SeparatedCaseState.NewWord;
                    }
                }
                else if (char.IsUpper(s[i]))
                {
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case SeparatedCaseState.Upper:
                            bool hasNext = (i + 1 < s.Length);
                            if (i > 0 && hasNext)
                            {
                                char nextChar = s[i + 1];
                                if (!char.IsUpper(nextChar) && nextChar != separator)
                                {
                                    sb.Append(separator);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case SeparatedCaseState.Lower:
                        case SeparatedCaseState.NewWord:
                            sb.Append(separator);
                            break;
                    }

                    char c;
                    c = char.ToLowerInvariant(s[i]);
                    sb.Append(c);

                    state = SeparatedCaseState.Upper;
                }
                else if (s[i] == separator)
                {
                    sb.Append(separator);
                    state = SeparatedCaseState.Start;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (state == SeparatedCaseState.NewWord)
                    {
                        sb.Append(separator);
                    }

                    sb.Append(s[i]);
                    state = SeparatedCaseState.Lower;
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The following model is used in the simple example:

```
    public class TestSerializer
    {
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public int CPUPower { get; set; } 
    }
```

And the example usage:

```
var data = new TestSerializer();
data.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
data.CPUPower = 10;

var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions 
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = new SnakeCaseNamingPolicy()
};
var json_string = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, serializeOptions);
Console.WriteLine(json_string);
```

gives `{"time_stamp":"2020-08-06T00:30:35.3815583-04:00","cpu_power":10}`

Answer (score 2):

As of .Net 8 (preview 2) there will be native support for:

- [CamelCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonnamingpolicy.camelcase?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-jsonnamingpolicy-camelcase)
- [KebabCaseLower](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonnamingpolicy.kebabcaselower?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-jsonnamingpolicy-kebabcaselower)
- [KebabCaseUpper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonnamingpolicy.kebabcaseupper?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-jsonnamingpolicy-kebabcaseupper)
- [**SnakeCaseLower**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonnamingpolicy.snakecaselower?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-jsonnamingpolicy-snakecaselower)
- [**SnakeCaseUpper**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonnamingpolicy.snakecaseupper?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-jsonnamingpolicy-snakecaseupper)

See also: [JsonNamingPolicy properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonnamingpolicy.snakecaseupper?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-jsonnamingpolicy-snakecaseupper)

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit late, but this solution will also solve cases like ABCItem or MyCPU.
This is just the concept, you can refine it to make it more versatile

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Extensions
{
    public static class StringExtension
    {
        public static string ToSnakeCase(this string str)
        {
            // collect the final result
            var snakeCase = new List<char>();

            // check and add chars (using for loop for performance)
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0 && char.IsUpper(str[i]) && !char.IsUpper(str[i + 1]))
                {
                    snakeCase.Add('_');
                }
                snakeCase.Add(str[i]);
            }

            // build the new string
            return new string(snakeCase.ToArray()).ToLower();
        }
    }
}

var snakeCase = "CPUMeter".ToSnakeCase();
var snakeCase = "PascalCase".ToSnakeCase();
var snakeCase = "camelCase".ToSnakeCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a seperate kebab- and snake- case naming policy.
Also, if you absolutely want to minimize the number of unnecceesary character-conversions and lookups, the conversion method can be somewhat optimized

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;

public class SeperatorNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
{
    public SeperatorNamingPolicy(char seperator = '_')
    {
        Seperator = seperator;
    }
    public char Seperator { get; }

    public override string ConvertName(string name)
    {
        IEnumerable<char> ToSeperated()
        {
            var e = name.GetEnumerator();
            if (!e.MoveNext()) yield break;
            yield return char.ToLower(e.Current);
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                if (char.IsUpper(e.Current))
                {
                    yield return Seperator;
                    yield return char.ToLower(e.Current);
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return e.Current;
                }
            }
        }

        return new string(ToSeperated().ToArray());
    }
}
```

However, if you just want a snake case naming policy without adding additional dependencies to your code, a dedicated snakecasenamingpolicy suffices:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;

public class SnakeCaseNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
{
    public override string ConvertName(string name)
    {
        static IEnumerable<char> ToSnakeCase(CharEnumerator e)
        {
            if (!e.MoveNext()) yield break;
            yield return char.ToLower(e.Current);
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                if (char.IsUpper(e.Current))
                {
                    yield return '_';
                    yield return char.ToLower(e.Current);
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return e.Current;
                }
            }
        }

        return new string(ToSnakeCase(name.GetEnumerator()).ToArray());
    }
}
```

You can of course use this by adding the json options in your startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // . . .
    services
        .AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = new SnakeCaseNamingPolicy());
    // . . .
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        static IEnumerable<char> ToSnakeCase(CharEnumerator e)
        {
            if (!e.MoveNext()) yield break;
            var wasLower = char.IsLower(e.Current);
            yield return char.ToLower(e.Current);
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                var isLower = char.IsLower(e.Current);
                if (wasLower && !isLower)
                {
                    yield return '_';
                }

                wasLower = isLower;

                yield return char.ToLower(e.Current);
            }
        }
```

Comment: There are **seven existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with over **forty votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.