# How do I default a c# Func optional parameter

Tags: c#

I would like a Func<float,float> parameter to a method but default it to a static function:

```
public Animation(float timeForAnimation,Vector target, Func<float, float> ease = Ease.nothing)
```

where Ease.nothing is a static function:

```
 public static float nothing(float f)
        {
            return MathUtil.clamp(0, f, 1);
        }
```

I am getting an error: 'Default parameter value for 'ease' must be a compile-time constant' .. not sure what that means or how i can get it to work

Comment: @gunr2171 Thanks - unfortunately it does answer the question, not what i was hping for but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Default values of parameters *must* be constants. In this case, the only such a constant is `null`.

What you can do, is resolve that within the body of `Animation`.

```
public void Animation(float timeForAnimation,Vector target, Func<float, float> ease = null)
{
    // in case of 'null' call the default Ease.Nothing() method
    var easedTime = (ease ?? Ease.Nothing)(timeForAnimation);
}
```

*Side note: Let me suggest you stick to the [UpperCamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) naming convention for method names.*

Comment: I think you're actually meaning `PascalCase`. The `camelCase` notation has the hump in the middle. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41769355/5171120