# Laravel 9 Mutating Attribute not returning mutated attribute

Tags: php, laravel

Environment

- Laravel 9
- php 8.0

I have this mutator function to transform a value from 4 decimal places to 2 decimal places. I want to test out but the `Attribute::make` function not returning value, below is code for the model

```
class SubjectWithFee extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sjfee';
    protected $primaryKey = 'IndexID';

    protected $fillable  = [
        'Amount',
        'CurrencyID',
        'ProgramID',
        ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected function Amount(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => sprintf('%0.2f', $value),
        );
    }
```

Although when I did the test it access the attribute correctly when putting `dd('test')` before the return but on the `get` function cannot be access

Anyone knows the problem?

**Update**

The column "Amount" starts with capital letter

Initially the source code was from laravel version 5 and someone upgraded to 9.

**Update 2**

All my setters are working, but only getters are not.

Comment: i tried your code in my env and it is working properly, do you have more insight ?

Comment: Try changing uppercase `Amount()` *protected* method to lowercase `amount()`

Comment: @jmvcollaborator I have update on the post

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa the column "Amount" starts with capital letter and I based that naming for the mutator from laravel docs

Comment: @nyx97 The **method name** should be in "camel case". *An accessor transforms an Eloquent attribute value when it is accessed. To define an accessor, create a protected method on your model to represent the accessible attribute. This method name **should** correspond to the **"camel case"** representation of the true underlying model attribute / database column when applicable.* [Defining An Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

Comment: @nyx97 [Camel case and Pascal case mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768733/camel-case-and-pascal-case-mistake)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa camel case only applicable if the name of your database column is something like "first_name" then you can name it "firstName" in method attribute. How about if the database column is something like mine "Amount", although I already tested that case you link of yours still not working, as I test all of mutators only getters are not working all of my setters are working well

Answer (score 0):

Try this different approach, instead of the current function you have:

```
public function getAmountAttribute($value)
    {
        return sprintf('%0.2f', $value);

    }
```

Comment: already done this one, its not working anymore on laravel 9

Comment: it is working on my end, and im running the same versions as yours

Comment: its not working on my end, only setters are working all of the get attribute is not working, do you have any idea?

Comment: the only difference is that my field is defined in lowercase

Answer (score 0):

*Add the attribute name to the appends property of your model.*

---

[Appending Values To JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

> Occasionally, when converting models to arrays or JSON, you may wish
> to add attributes that do not have a corresponding column in your
> database. To do so, first define an
> [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators) for the
> value:
>
> After creating the accessor, add the attribute name to the `appends`
> property of your model. Note that attribute names are typically
> referenced using their "snake case" serialized representation, even
> though the accessor's PHP method is defined using "camel case":

> ```php
> <?php
>  
> namespace App\Models;
>  
> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
>  
> class User extends Model
> {
>     /**
>      * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
>      *
>      * @var array
>      */
>     protected $appends = ['amount'];
> }
> ```